# Flask loading icon on page load

Tags: javascript, flask

```js
from flask import Flask, render_template, Response, request, redirect, url_for

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['TEMPLATES_AUTO_RELOAD'] = True



@app.route("/", methods=["POST", "GET"])
def index():
    if request.method == "POST":
        return render_template("index.html")
        
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>



<style> 
  div#loading {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    display: none;
    background: url('https://i.giphy.com/3oEjI6SIIHBdRxXI40.gif') center no-repeat;
    cursor: wait;
    padding-left:100%;
    }  
</style>
</head>
  
<body>
<form method="POST">
    <input type="text">
    <button type="submit" onclick="loading();">
      <div id="loading"></div>
      <div id="content">
        <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
      </div>
    </button> 
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function loading(){
      $("#loading").show();
      $("#content").hide();       
  }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm building a Flask app, where when you press a button, a loader should replace the search glass icon with a loading gif.

At the moment, the gif isn't appearing upon clicking the button.

When I remove `display:none` from the loading style, the gif appears, so I know it's there.

Comment: `https://media.giphy.com/media/3oEjI6SIIHBdRxXI40/giphy.gif` is an HTML page, not a GIF. `https://i.giphy.com/3oEjI6SIIHBdRxXI40.gif` is a GIF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured I already had a `div id = content` and so it was removing the entire div. Remember to check your IDs!

Answer (score 0):

You are using JQuery to show and hide the elements, but you have not included it in the template.

So include a script tag like

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

before the script tag where you're referencing JQuery

Comment: Thanks! I've edited my code snippet to include JQuery. Although it works here, it doesn't seem to work on my Flask app. There's enough load time because it takes around 3 seconds for the next page to appear. Any ideas?

Comment: I would debug the loading function. If you put a log at the end of the loading function do you see it in the console?
What happens if you move the button to a place outside the form? So a button with the same `onclick` property, without the `type` property and outside the form element. Does it still not work in that case? Probably unrelated but in your flask route you only seem to render the template on POST request, why is that?

Comment: I did all of the above and figured out that I already had a div id = content. *rolls eyes*. Thanks for your help!